# How exactly does the stacking context work in css?

Tags: html, css, z-index

[Stacking contexts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IssRO.png)

As you can see in the image I have the following structure:

```css
#container {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}

#child1 {
  background-color: greenyellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

#child1a {
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 40;
}

#child2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: violet;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="child1">
    <div id="child1a" />
  </div>

  <div id="child2" />
</div>
```

As I understand, child1 should not create a new stacking context since I do not specify z-index. Therefore the parent stacking context of child1a should be same as the parent context for child2 and since the z-index of child1a is bigger than that of child2 is should be above child2, what am I missing here?

Comment: you didn't set position for child1a

Comment: it depends on the browser, it's not standardize, the z-index system used in chrome for example use a "relative" rule (child z-index is relative to the parent z-index) where other browser (IE) uses an absolute z-index (z-index: 999 is the same thing for each element on the page)

Comment: `z-index` only works on positioned elements. That is, elements with a `position` other than the default of `static`

Comment: @Berto99 it doesn't depend on browser and there is a whole Spec detailing this so it's a standard that all the browser should follow: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html

Comment: Thank you! Now everything is on its own place